# Faucet drain plug chain attachment

Tags: drain

Where does the drain plug chain attach on the faucet? We are installing a vintage faucet in our tub, but can’t locate where the drain plug chain attaches to the faucet.

Comment: The faucet may not have an attachment point. In which case you'll be adding one as a separate item. But if you [edit] to add a photo, (sun and mountains icon along the top) someone might be able to see if there is one you're missing. My vague recollection of actual vintage tubs is they usually attached to the overflow cover.

Answer (score 1):

There would typically be a loop on the overflow cover plate that would be used to
attach the loop at the end of the chain. Some faucets would also have a built-in similar loop.